# F.lux indicator on wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

Is there anyway to have the f.lux indicator look native to elementary OS?

Maybe just black and white?

[image: wingpanel]

Comment: I couldn't even get the indicator showing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install elementaryplus
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Activating Core Icon theme on the elementary+ Configurator worked. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using another icon pack, like [Papirus](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme). They have integrated support for [Hardcode-Tray](https://github.com/bil-elmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray) and will make all your icons from wingpanel look like native.

Comment: I tried this and it said `no apps to fix`. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hey @fpigeonjr, the main dev of Hardcode-Tray here. Please report this issue upstream with some more information and i will help you sort this out (or fix it if it's an issue). Thanks!